# Faithful projective representations of symmetric groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

This is a reference request.

Do you know where I can find the dimensions of the faithful projective representations of $S_n$ and $A_n$ for $n\ge 5$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Faithful is not really important, since non-faithful rep factors through the group on 2 elements, which is not that hard to tackle.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe it's worth adding a reference to a modern treatment of Schur's work in book form, which might be easier to read than the original paper of Schur (note that I'm unrelated to the authors):

P.N. Hoffman and J.F. Humphreys, *Projective representations of the symmetric groups.*
Q-functions and shifted tableaux.
Oxford Mathematical Monographs.
Oxford Science Publications.
The Clarendon Press, Oxford University Press, New York, 1992.

Answer (score 8):

See Schur's original paper

Schur, I. (1911), *Über die Darstellung der symmetrischen und der 
alternierenden Gruppe durch gebrochene lineare Substitutionen*,
Crelle's Journal 139: 155–250. ([EuDML](https://eudml.org/doc/149348))